# CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I added **HTTPPinning** to OKHTTPClient the sample code is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.setSslSocketFactory(getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(context));


private SSLSocketFactory getPinnedCertSslSocketFactory(Context context) {
    try {
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream incontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.prod_keystore);
        trusted.load(in, "venkat@123".toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyApp", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

> **I uploaded the app into playstore and from the last 1 year on wards it is working good. but from the last 1 week onwards it is giving the below issue and I used OkHttp of version com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.4**
>
> ```
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for 
>           certification path not found.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>                   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
>                   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
>                   at com.venkat.good.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:492)
>                   at com.venkat.good.http.MyHTTPThread.run(MyHTTPThread.java:76)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
> ```

by using OKHTTP3 i resolved this issue.

```
String hostname = "yourdomain.com";
  CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
 .add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
 .build();
   OkHttpClient client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
 .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
 .build();

  Request request = new Request.Builder()
 .url("https://" + hostname)
 .build();
 client.newCall(request).execute();
```

> **But I want to know why the previous OkHttp2 version works for some days and after that it raises the issue?**

Comment: Is there a chance that something changed on the server side or that the certificate expired?

Comment: I didn't specify any date while creating the BKS file  and the server people didn't change anything at their side.

Answer (score 0):

**Better late than never**

Glad you managed your problem with `OkHttp3`.

---

**Let me just answer your asked sub question:**

This was a build system configuration problem, not a problem with `OkHttp`.
Everyone was surprised to see to behave that way because it should be
resolving the higher version required by `OkHttp3` for use.
If you were using `maven` or `retrofit` a fix has been merged into the newer version (`OkHttp3` implemented it for the mentioned libraries).